# Sql - Correct Sum of field of base table with left outer join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have this method which returns the final result for me to show, I have amount field in order table After this query I want that sum of amount field but at the same time I can't change `get_raw_records` because left outer join & filters is required

```
def get_raw_records
  Order.includes(:customers, :line_items).where(aasm_state: ['completed']).filers(.....)
end

get_raw_records.sum(:amount)
```

This sum is not correct as it has duplicate orders because of left outer join with line items

I am trying some other ways like but it distinct the amount not order records

```
get_raw_records.distinct.sum(:amount)
```

Any help to do this?, I can't change `get_raw_records` base query

Comment: why not simply write a new query ? Aggregation tasks would be faster in SQL than ruby

Comment: Yes I am trying @SudiptaMondal

Answer (score 0):

before execute second query data may had change.
you need to add in query such field -

```
sum(amount) over() as need_summ
```

and just use this value from either result row

Comment: can you explain this a bit?

Comment: Sum is aggregate function and returned only one value or need group by clouse. When we add over() we made sum function as window and it no more need group by clouse.

Comment: But we I am using left outer join on line_items , so 1 order may repeat multiple times and SUM will aggregate same order multiple times.